# Как настроить Logback PatternLayoutEncoder?

Tags: spring, java-ee, логирование

К примеру есть класс User c полями username, status и т.д.
Есть конфигурация encoder'a logback:

```
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <outputPatternAsHeader>true</outputPatternAsHeader>
        <pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
</encoder>
```

Как настроить конфигурацию logback так, чтоюбы можно было вставлять свои переменные в паттерн.
К примеру: %name:%status - %msg%n